# Problems with menu

Tags: html, css

Is there a way so that when I open my menu, it does not go beyond the first section or scrolling will be disabled once the menu is open? I tried giving every section z-index 999 but that does not work

HTML:

```
<section class="intro">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="menu">
    <span class="hamburger"></span>
  </span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</label>
<div class="text">
<h1>my<br>example<br>text</h1>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<section class="first"> 

</section>

<section class="second">  

</section>


<section class="third">  

</section>
```

CSS:

```
/* Section styling */
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  height: 100vh;
}

.intro {
  background-color:#291411;
}

.first {
  background-color:#834940;
}

.second {
  background-color:#291411;
}

.third {
  background-color:#834940;
}
/* Hide scrollbars */
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px; 
    background: transparent; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
/* Menu before */
label .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #291411;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

label .hamburger:after, label .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #291411;
}

label .hamburger:before { top: -10px; }

label .hamburger:after { bottom: -10px; }

label input { display: none; }

label input:checked + .menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #E0C9B7, 0 0 0 100vh #E0C9B7;
  border-radius: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu + ul { opacity: 1; }
/* Menu after */
label .menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #E0C9B7;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #E0C9B7, 0 0 0 0 #E0C9B7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  list-style-type:none;
}

label a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #291411;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Footer styling */
footer {
  padding: 1% 5%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #291411;
  color: #E0C9B7;
}
```

To disable the scroll when the menu is open I tried to add overflow-x:hidden to the html and body but this makes the whole page weird

Comment: You can make the list fixed, so that it doesn't scroll with the page... [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gycdqgv0/)

Comment: When I change the list to fixed, the text from the menu when it is open, scrolls along above every section

Answer (score 0):

Did a simple solution with jquery, you can do this with javascript. I used jquery just to save time.

```js
$(".js-change").on("change", function() {
  $("html").toggleClass("menu-open");  
});
```

```css
/* Section styling */
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  height: 100vh;
}

.intro {
  background-color:#291411;
}

.first {
  background-color:#834940;
}

.second {
  background-color:#291411;
}

.third {
  background-color:#834940;
}
/* Hide scrollbars */
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px; 
    background: transparent; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
/* Menu before */
label .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #291411;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

label .hamburger:after, label .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #291411;
}

label .hamburger:before { top: -10px; }

label .hamburger:after { bottom: -10px; }

label input { display: none; }

label input:checked + .menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #E0C9B7, 0 0 0 100vh #E0C9B7;
  border-radius: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu .hamburger:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
}

label input:checked + .menu + ul { opacity: 1; }
/* Menu after */
label .menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #E0C9B7;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #E0C9B7, 0 0 0 0 #E0C9B7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  list-style-type:none;
}

label a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #291411;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Footer styling */
footer {
  padding: 1% 5%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #291411;
  color: #E0C9B7;
}

.menu-open,
.menu-open body {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="intro">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="js-change">
  <span class="menu">
    <span class="hamburger"></span>
  </span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</label>
<div class="text">
<h1>my<br>example<br>text</h1>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<section class="first"> 

</section>

<section class="second">  

</section>


<section class="third">  

</section>
```